# Access ajax event listener on custom object

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code to make an ajax file upload request. But I have multiple files and multiple pages to upload from so wanted to try to make it in to an object that i can reuse.

```
function upload(url,formdata){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST",url);
    xhr.upload.onloadstart = function (e) {
        //something something....
        x='hello';
    }
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
        //something something...
        y='world';
    }
    xhr.upload.onloadend = function (e) {
        //something something...
    }
    xhr.send(formdata);
}

foo=new upload("https://example.com",formdata);
```

Now, my question is, how can I "pass on" or expose, the events to 'foo' so I could do something like this:

```
foo=new upload(
    "https://example.com",formdata
).onloadstart(
   //do whatever here, have access to x
).onprogress(
   //do whatever here, have access to y
)
```

My research tells me I need to use method chaining, or rather, that is what it is called, and I need to add

```
return this;
```

to each of the events, but thats as far as i get.

grateful for any help!